# How to determine which node module packages are compatible with others?

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I inherited an Angular application from somebody who is no longer available to answer questions.

The application hasn't been updated in several years, and is behind in node module package versions.

I don't yet want to upgrade to the latest versions of all packages.

My question is:  How can I ensure that all of the packages that I upgrade are compatible with each other?

For example, let's say that I start with a specific version of @angular/cli.  Then I want to know which versions of typescript are compatible with it.  Then I want to do the same for @schematics/package-update, ng2-semantic, webpack, and on and on.

Do I have to manually research each and every package, and try to figure out which releases are compatible with other packages?

Or is there some way I can run `npm install --save <package_name>`, and have npm determine and install, based on dependencies, a version of the package that is compatible with other packages that are already installed?

Are there any other methods/suggestions?

Comment: You know which version of node the app code belongs to, I recommend that you use NVM for development, Angular will not allow you to install libraries that are not compatible and if you want to be completely sure that the app works, do a build after installing the library.

Comment: My understanding of nvm is that it allows you to switch between multiple versions of node and npm.  I don't understand how that would help me much with the individual node module packages though.  I still need to know which version(s) of each package are compatible with other packages.